# Ensure that SQL is properly escaped when writing SQL scripts for a migration

Tags: java, mysql, sql, escaping

We're currently trying to migrate data from one database to another. This migration is not exactly straightforward, so it cannot be done by simply executing some update statements. We therefore need to read the source data with a program and then **generate an update SQL script to a file** which will insert the converted data into the target database. This file is later run by an administrator against the target database.

Normally one would use **prepared statements** for this and not care about escaping at all but in this case **we actually want to generate SQL that is going to be printed into a file** and **executed manually at a later time**. The reason for this is that no software may be installed in the target environment. So because we are not directly sending SQL to our target database, in our case prepared statements are of no help.

Do you know of a way to generate the result SQL after performing the database migration with a tool in-memory which ensures that everything is escaped correctly in the generated SQL files?

Comment: We once ended up with a similar requirement. What we did was to write a program in C# which would loop through all our schema table names & generated a textfile with our required statements.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why this was down-voted. It seems like a totally legitimate question.

Comment: This sort of question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but you could probably whip it up into a decent question over on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (but please read their [on-topic guidelines](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first!).

Comment: What does "executed manually" mean, exactly? Can the data migration process not be automated using code which can use prepared statements as well? That way you can store the values separately from the SQL again...

Comment: Nope, the requirement is to produce a SQL file containing all required statements. That file will then be executed by an administrator on the target environment. No software may be installed on that environment. I am not too happy about this requirement, but I don't make the rules for that project.

Comment: Why do you need to use Java to generate this file? Wouldn't a dedicated tool along the lines of `mysqldump` be more suitable?

Comment: Because we need to do some more or less complex transformations on the source data, which cannot be easily done by mysqldump or pure SQL.

Comment: @JanThomä: how about creating an intermediate DB with your transformed data and dumping *that*? Quite honestly, manipulating SQL code sounds like a recipe for disaster - the kind of disaster that you only find out about six months later when it's too late...

Comment: @thkala that is actually a GREAT idea :) If you post this as a full answer I'd select that as accepted answer and you'll get some rep for it :).

Comment: @JanThomä: If you can, please edit your question to make it broader by asking for alternative approaches. As it is, it is mainly asking for a software recommendation, which is off-topic for SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating or manipulating SQL code on your own sounds like a recipe for disaster. It's a good way to silently corrupt your data in subtle ways that may become visible months or years later, when it's too late to correct.

If you want to migrate data, you should use a dedicated tool for your database, such as [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html). The tool will ensure that *any* data is escaped properly and will also take care of all kinds of other details that you have probably not even thought about.

If your data is not ready for migration as-is, then a possible solution would be to *massage* your data into the proper schema/format using an intermediate database for the output. Your can then dump the intermediate database safely using the aforementioned dedicated tool.